# Does anyone know of any good Asubha sites?

Tags: theravada

Does anyone know of any good Asubha sites?  Am interested in suitable objects for contemplation for the overcoming of lust.

Comment: Requests for link lists are off topic, but requests for thematic material for ashubha/Patikulamanasikara is on topic. A link list would be low quality info, since the links rapidly turn into 404s.

Comment: We haven't really come to a consensus on this @MatthewMartin; see [here](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/11/should-requests-for-materials-be-considered-on-topic): maybe this will be a good test - anyone want to cast close votes?

Comment: I would vote to close, but don't have the rep to do it yet. My problem with this question is not that is is asking for resources, but that it is a list question. There is no single definitive answer on list questions and there will always be one more site to add. That's why list questions are off-topic on most SE sites (with some exceptions, but in those cases list questions are usually made community-wiki questions)

Answer (score 1):

I think these might be helpful:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2JroFk5Ke8

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgDHJzBt-YU

I found it more helpful in daily life to be more aware of and look more at old people. I find it also develops helps develop a sense of respect towards fellow humans around. Old people are worthy objects of respect.

No need then for so much blood and gore. Or I have not seen the advantage of it.

I think it all depends from where one works. A sense awareness that there is the same awareness in the object, being bound to this existence, growing old, sick and dying, from my experience, is a very powerful support. More than looking at dead bodies.

Might be different for others.

After that one incident, where I looked at a woman like this, because "fallen in love", could not maintain such enamoured state, because somehow it was demeaning, my thought was I wanted to disappear into the forest and only look at my own mind, to find freedom.

Then looking at any woman at all I was not inclined to have any sexually motivated perception or fantasy anymore for months on end. Feeling very light and freed.

So, this sense, that we are all imprisoned here, going to die. Developing this at the "living object", developes some kind of compassion that one would not be able to have sexual thoughts about this.

Perhaps a bit gone of-topic, because just I find some other ways to be more useful.

Just some not so professional ideas. Hope it may help.

_/_

Comment: And another one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56LMAamf78A
because could only post one link at once with only so many "credit" points.

Answer (score 0):

See and memorize dissected cadavers. Blood filled bodies after accidents. Imaginate the stools and think that they from inside the body are good points.